# angular app encoding German character as gibberish

Tags: html, angular, character-encoding

I have created an Angular 5 application which have German characters. I am working on IntelliJ IDE and have problem in using german characters in html. As per the information already given in these tickets [How can I properly display German characters in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423693/how-can-i-properly-display-german-characters-in-html)
 and [How can I use special characters in angular directives attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31591885/angularjs-encoding-german-umlauts), I have added the following lines in my html file:

```
<html xml:lang="de" lang="de">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" charset="utf-8" />
</head>
...
```

Also, I have set the file encoding type to UTF-8 in the IDE.

When I compile the code, I can see that they are correctly encoded in the webpack files but when I deploy (openshift deployment), I get gibberish in place of German umlauts: [Image with incorrect Encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylTJt.png)

Though when I refresh the page once, it gets corrected: [Image with correct Enoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqHVK.png)

Can anybody please assist with this issue?

Comment: Are you by any chance using server side rendering?

Comment: I am deploying this application on a cloud openshift server. I am not entirely sure about server side rendering. Any way to check it?